# Service has no exported member 'member-variablke'

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am privateley working on a little page for stats from an online game. It worked fine till now. But now I have an issue: when I try to compile my program with ng serve, the console gives me the message "'...src/app/Services/riot-connector.service"' has no exported member 'dataFromRiot'

I've watched other projects where I did the same, but could not discover any mistakes in my code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { idData } from '../Models/id-data';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RiotConnectorService {
  private dataFromRiot: string =
  'https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=RGAPI-b40ae023-1ab9-4e11-a274-0b91afee5b25';

  private readonly header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'content-type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(
      private http: HttpClient
      ) { }

  getPlayerId(): Observable<idData[]> {
    return this.http.get<idData[]>(this.dataFromRiot, {headers: this.header});
  }

}
```

He should compile fine - but the compiler says: 
 ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module '"D:/.../.../.../src/app/Services/riot-connector.service"' has no exported member 'dataFromRiot'.

Comment: first check, in which module your declare this service. and then check in which module you are importing this service. if both are not the same module then you need to export the service in that module where you declare this service and then import the module where you want to use this service.

Comment: I think you do not import your service in your module check your module.

Comment: You might want to remove the API Key (from this question / not from the code).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I Imported the class instead of the service in app.module - now it compiled. Thanks a lot! Awsome!

Comment: it is just a private key which expires in about 20 minutes.. so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error might be in your `app.module.ts` file. Are you trying to access the `dataFromRiot` variable there?